# jquery - click events in the success part of ajax call not triggered

Tags: jquery, ajax

1st working case: I am sending an ajax call to my MVC controller, when the controller returns with success It displays a popover which I have the possibility to close when clicking on "Hide".

This is the code:

```
         $.ajax({
            cache : false,
            url: "http://localhost:8080/controller",
            type: "POST",
            data:  JSON.stringify(jsonSequenceList),
            contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(result) {

                    $('#divtodisplayresult').html(result);
                    $('#search-button').popover({
                        html : true,
                        title: "Consider also Searching for:",
                        content: function() {
                            return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();  
                        }
                    }).popover('show');

                    $("#hidepopover").click(function(){
                        $('#search-button').popover().popover('hide');
                    });

            }

        });
```

2nd NOT working case: Now when the controller returns, based on the result, I have two options to follow, the above and another one.

This is the code:

```
$.ajax({
            cache : false,
            url: "http://localhost:8080/recommender",
            type: "POST",
            data:  JSON.stringify(jsonSequenceList),
            contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.toString().indexOf("buckimg_popover_content_wrapper")){
                    $('#div2todisplayresult').html(result);
                    $('#query-wrapper').popover( {
                        html : true,
                        title: "Would you like add this to your collection?",
                        content: function() {
                            return $('#buckimg_popover_content_wrapper').html();                                  }
                    }).popover('show');
                    $("#noimg").click(function(){
                       $('#query-wrapper').popover().popover('hide');
                    });

                    $("#yesimg").click(function(){

                     //dostuff
                     $('#query-wrapper').popover().popover('hide');

                    });


                }

                else{
                $('#divtodisplayresult').html(result);
                $('#search-button').popover({
                    html : true,
                    title: "Consider also Searching for:",
                    content: function() {
                        return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();         
                    }
                }).popover('show');

                $("#hidepopover").click(function(){
                    $('#search-button').popover().popover('hide');
                });
            }
            }

        });
```

So my issue is that after the controller returns it correctly gets into the proper "if block" but when I click on 'No' or 'Yes' ($("#noimg").click(function(){}),  $("#yesimg").click(function(){}) ) the events are not caught and when I click on Hide the event ( $("#hidepopover").click(function(){})) again is not caught, while in the first attached working case it works fine.

I tried also to drag the three events outside the if/else block but still no luck. Could you help me work this out? Thank you.

Comment: Try `if (result.toString().indexOf("buckimg_popover_content_wrapper") !== -1)`

Comment: indexOf returns an integer, so for valid if checks, you check against -1 for not found or > -1 for found.

Comment: You are right both of you.. I was so tired that I didn't notice. Thank you very much.